# ServiceStack ormLite chaning OrderBy

Tags: c#, sql-order-by, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying to so the following:

```
var routines = con.Select<Table>(con.From<Table>().OrderBy(p => p.Field1).ThenBy(i => i.Field2));
```

The above works perfectly. But I want a rather more generic approach and parse a string like sort="field1,field2". I have the following code:

```
int sortFieldCount = 0;
var itemsq = con.From<Table>();
foreach (var name in orderByField.Split(',')) {
if(sortFieldCount == 0)
  itemsq = sortOrderAscending ? itemsq.OrderBy(name) : itemsq.OrderByDescending(name);
else
   itemsq = sortOrderAscending ? itemsq.ThenBy(name) : itemsq.ThenByDescending(name);
sortFieldCount++;
}
```

But the above code seems to overwrite the first OrderBy. Is there a solution to such a problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other ways you can perform multiple Order By's with [ServiceStack.OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) include:

```cs
var orderByAnonType = db.Select(db.From<Track>().OrderBy(x => new { x.Album, x.Name }));

var orderByString = db.Select(db.From<Track>().OrderByFields("Album","Name"));

// Use `-` prefix to inverse sort order, e.g. Album Descending
var orderByString = db.Select(db.From<Track>().OrderByFields("-Album","Name"));

var orderByArray = db.Select(db.From<Track>().OrderBy(x => new[]{ "Album","Name" }));
```

So you could get a flexible OrderBy like [AutoQuery's OrderBy](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#paging-and-ordering) with:

```cs
var fields = orderByString.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
q.OrderByFields(fields);
```

Here's a [live example of this](http://gistlyn.com/?gist=5194d3f3762249fa071fa82f7dde4c8a&collection=2cc6b5db6afd3ccb0d0149e55fdb3a6a) you can play around with on [gistlyn.com](http://gistlyn.com)

Answer (score -1):

There is a couple problems in the accepted answer I'd like to address.

First is the possibility of SQL injection attacks. ServiceStack does not fully validate what you pass in to the list of sort columns. While it will detect some of the more obvious attacks, you could still slip in things like calls to stored functions.

The second problem is descending sorts. It's not obvious from the API, but you can pass in `"columnName DESC"` rather than just `"columnName"`. In fact, this is how it is able to support `"Album,Name"`, it just passes it directly to SQL with the barest amount of validation.

```
public IList<Employee> SortBy(string lastName, string sortByColumnA, bool isDescendingA, string sortByColumnB, bool isDescendingB)
{
    if (!Utilities.EmployeeColumnNames.Contains(sortByColumnA))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(sortByColumnA), "Unknown column " + sortByColumnA);
    if (!Utilities.EmployeeColumnNames.Contains(sortByColumnB))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(sortByColumnB), "Unknown column " + sortByColumnB);

    var sortDirectionA = isDescendingA ? " DESC " : "";
    var sortDirectionB = isDescendingB ? " DESC " : "";

    using (var db = _dbConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection())
    {
        return db.Select(db.From<Employee>().Where(x => x.LastName == lastName)
            .OrderBy(sortByColumnA + sortDirectionA + "," + sortByColumnB + sortDirectionB)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Being able to call `.OrderBy("random()")` is a feature of the SQL Fragment APIs, and I object that my answer allows any kind of SQL Injection which uses known column names in both its typed and untyped APIs. A large part of OrmLite's flexibility is its SQL Fragment APIs which allows accessing RDBMS features. If you object to their existence don't use any ORM's API that lets you execute SQL fragments. Either way I've updated my answer to use `.OrderByFields()` which is validated.

Comment: Being able to call `.OrderBy("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE LEFT(Users.EMail,1) = LEFT(Employee.FirstName.EMail,1))")` is also a feature of the SQL Fragment APIs that people need to be aware of. 

The truth of the matter is that developers are going to pass unchecked user values to `OrderBy` and that can lead to security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Your example doesn't bypass the Illegal SQL Fragment Validation so no you can't call that. Irrespective If they're going to bypass the Typed APIs it should be understood that you shouldn't pass any unchecked User Input into free-text APIs.